# How Log POST/PUT/DELETE request came to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

How to log all POST/PUT/DELETE request that came to elasticsearch like API Gateway?

I tried with [slowlog](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/index-modules-slowlog.html) but it seems not working,  `lasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log` file showing empty always.
Is there any way to do so using any other plugin like logstash filebeat etc?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can deploy an NginX server and send the request through the Nginx server to Elasticsearch you can catch API calls.

Here is an example for you:
https://gist.github.com/joshuar/38a0196d29a9bc7bd971

[image]